# Installing python pip package from tar.gz with extra includes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have a python package being built, which also has two options for `extra_includes`:

```
name='mypackage',
extras_require={
    'option_one': ['dep1'],
    'option_two': ['dep2']
}
```

I only have access to the tar.gz built package which means I cannot simply do:

```
pip install mypackage[option_two]
```

Previously, I was directly installing this directly from the tar.gz:

```
pip install path/to/mypackage.tar.gz
```

However, this no longer allows me to specify the extra_require like:

```
pip install path/to/mypackage.tar.gz[option_two] # this is wrong
```

I could expand the package and do a manual install from the directory but is there a way to more directly install  from the tar.gz itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the pip [changelog](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/):

> 7.0.0 (2015-05-21)
>
> - Allowing using extras when installing from a file path without requiring the use of an editable ([PR #2785](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/2785)).

Some Linux distros bundle very old versions of pip when using the system packages for virtualenv or venv. Update pip after creating your env.

```
pip install -U pip
pip install package.tar.gz[name]
```